# React list duplicate items

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner at react and I wanted to test what a learn so far with a TODO app.

When I insert the first task it goes well, but when I insert the second this error appears

> index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `xo05w2021082017`.

And the output of every insert go like this:
[image: 1]

When I only insert up to 5, but they keep duplicating themselves.

This is the code from App.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import InputBar from './components/InputBar';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = { todoItems: [] }
  onInputSubmit = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      todoItems: this.state.todoItems.concat(text)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <InputBar onSubmit={this.onInputSubmit}></InputBar>
        <TodoList todoItems={this.state.todoItems}></TodoList>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
import { getCurrentDate } from '../util/CurrentDate';

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  state = { arr: [] }

  render() {
    const key = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)
    const separate = "";

    const renderedList = this.props.todoItems.map((text) => {

      console.log('doing it');
      return (
        <TodoItem key={`${key}${separate}${getCurrentDate()}`} text={text} />
      );
    })
    console.log(renderedList)
    return (
      <div className="ui list">
        {renderedList}
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default TodoList;
```

TodoItem.js

```js
import React from 'react';

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className="content">
          <div className="header">
            {this.props.text}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error should be self descriptive. Here:

```
    const key = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)
```

you are generating that random number *once during a render*, then you pass it as part of `key` for *all* items. Apparently `getCurrentDate` doesn't generate different strings either - but even if it did, it is still bad practice to generate keys like that in render, because *the same item* would have a different key on each render. On the other hand, keys must be *stable*. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

The best place to generate that key in your case would be when you add a new item, create a key for it inside the `onInputSubmit` method. You will need to change your code a bit because now together with `text` you must also store a key for that item.